# Как вывести список произвольных записей wordpress, исключая текущую?

Tags: wordpress

Данный код выводит список записей `post_type - post` стандартной рубрики `category`. Как вывести записи `post_type - FILM` таксономии (рубрики) HORROR?

```
<?php
$mycat=get_the_category();
$mycat=$mycat[0];
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category='.$mycat->cat_ID.'&exclude='.$post->ID);
    foreach($posts as $post) :?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $post;
// получаем список категорий текущего поста
// предполагаем что все в таксономии info
    foreach( get_the_terms($post->ID,'info') as $cur_term ){
    $terms[] = $cur_term->slug;
}

// получаем 20 постов из категорий текущего поста
// за исключением самого текущего поста
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 20,
            'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'info',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $terms
        )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
    ));

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
                   echo '<div>';
                     echo '<a href="';
                     the_permalink();
                     echo '"class="title">';
                     the_title();
                     echo '</a>';
                    the_excerpt();
                    echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

помогли с тостера